# Non-significant effect but significant coefficient. Should I remove the effect?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, bivariate

I did a logistic regression.

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2(X_2=1) + \beta_3(X_2 = 2)$

All of the predictors are categorical. $X_1$ has two level e.g. Yes/No, $X_2$ has three levels e.g. Low/Medium/High.

The likelihood Ratio Tests showed one of the IVs is not significant (Chi-square = 4.73, df = 2, p=0.094). Let's say this variable is $X_2$.

However, one of the coefficients of $X_2$ is significant e.g. $\beta_3$.

Suppose the final model is $Y = -0.09 + 0.78X_1 + 0.5(X_2 = Medium) + 0.6(X_2 = High)$

My question is

1) Should I remove $X_2$ from the model then re-run the regression? since the effect of $X_2$ is not significant. What if the analysis aim is to find relationship of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in changes in OR of Y?

2) Is it correct to interpret that: $X_2$ has no statistically significant effect on the model. The log odds ratio of approving the application is increased if the income is high compared to low (p=0.038).

Comment: At the moment your estimate of the effect of $X_1$ is adjusted for $X_2$. That may be desirable even if $X_2$ is not significant. It depends on the scientific questions.

Comment: So, if the analysis aim is to find the relationship of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in changes in the odds ratio of Y, then you suggested that I keep both $X_1$ and $X_2$ in the model? Do I need to report that $x_2$ is not significant or only report the significant coefficient? Thanks.

Comment: Report everything. To keep both or not to keep both is a scientific question not a statistical one. For instance in a study of dementia you would always include age even if it happened in your sample not to be significant.